# Problema System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

estoy queriendo mandar a mi WS Reference el Cuit y pedidoCliente y lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConexionWS(string cuit, string pedidocliente, string dirmail, string acepta)
    {            
        cuit = CleanString(cuit);
        
        zWsCustomerInvoiceGetList.Customerid = cuit;
        zWsCustomerInvoiceGetList.PedidoSap = "";
        zWsCustomerInvoiceGetList.PedidoCli = "";            

        var resultado = client.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListAsync(zWsCustomerInvoiceGetList); //ERROR AC
        }
```

El método ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListAsync() espera un ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList.

Y bueno cuando compilo me salta el error del titulo:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'

En esta linea

```
var resultado = client.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListAsync(zWsCustomerInvoiceGetList);
```

Estará esperando algo que no le estoy mandando?

Si necesitan algo haganmelo saber.

**EDIT:**

Pude resolver ese error, era simplemente generar un client.OpenAsync();
Pero al hacerlo me salto éste error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: 'El objeto de comunicación, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ServiceReference1.Z_WS_CUSTOMER_INVOICE_GET_LIST], no se puede usar para la comunicación porque se encuentra en el estado Faulted.

Answer (score 0):

Me faltaba el client.OpenAsync(); Pero ahora me salta otro error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: 'El objeto de comunicación, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ServiceReference1.Z_WS_CUSTOMER_INVOICE_GET_LIST], no se puede usar para la comunicación porque se encuentra en el estado Faulted.'

Tengo que crear otra pregunta?

Comment: En realidad también podías (editar)[https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/535274/edit] tu pregunta

Comment: okis, ahi va, gracias